# Unsubscribe publication list through salesforce

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, api, soap-api, marketingcloudapi

Does someone have an example solution for me? I want to Unsubscribe/ Active people on publication list through salesforce? I want to map certain checkboxes in Salesforce to Publication lists in Marketing Cloud. Do we need the SOAP API for this/ or could this be acheaved another way?

**Use Case**

1. Uncheck checkbox Newsletter x --> Unsubscribe that Contact id from Publicationlist Newsletter x
2. Check checkbox Newsletter x --> Resubscribe that Contact id from Publicationlist Newsletter x

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of achieving this:

1. Create an APEX trigger in Sales/Service Cloud, that initiates a SOAP-API call to Salesforce every time the field is changed. This solution would immediately update the publication list.
2. Synchronize the checkbox fields to Marketing Cloud via Marketing Cloud Connect and create an Automation that checks for differences between the publication list(s) (via data views) and the synchronized data extension. You then need to do a data extension extract, move that file to the import directory of your enhanced ftp (file transfer activity) and then import the file to your publication list(s) using an import activity.

**Related documentation:**

- [Data View: ListSubscribers](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_listsubscribers.htm&type=5)
- [SOAP API Documentation: Manage Subscribers On Lists](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/managing_subscribers_on_lists.htm)